# How to compare the two table row count , if counts matches than ok if not matches this will restart the SSIS package

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have made the ssis package in which i made the data flow for incremental data. Source and destination server ip's are different. Below you can find the flow diagram of my package[Control flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd7aD.png) 
[Data flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmiB9.png)
the package is working fine . 
In the Execute SQl task :- it controls the log table and start the incremental task 
query which i used is :-

```
insert into audit_log (
Packagename,
process_date,
start_datetime,
end_datetime,
Record_processed,
status
)values('CRM-TO-TRANSORGDB',null,GETDATE(),null,null,null);

select MAX(ID) as ID,MAX(process_date) as proc_date  from audit_log where Packagename ='CRM-TO-TRANSORGDB' ;
```

store the ID and proc_date in the variable.

in the Execute SQl task 1:- it just update the log table.

```
UPDATE audit_log
SET
process_date=?,
end_datetime = GETDATE(),
status='SUCCESS'
record_processed=?
WHERE (packagename = 'CRM-TO-TRANSORGDB') AND ID=? ;
```

this is the query we have used to update the log table.

In the Data flow simple fetching the all the records and put in into the destination table.
this all i have done .
But my question are:-
**1) How to compare the total no. of row counts from the source table to destination table in ssis package.
2) if its doesn't matches than it will restart my task automatically.**

@thomas as per your instruction i have done the following thing:
1) i have made the Execute SQl Task for source and destination .
2) and Add the Execute Package task and added the condition for not matching the count.

[image: add the execute SQL Task for the source and destination]

and added the expression for check row_count_src!= row_count_dest

and in Source_table_count i have used the below query:

```
select count(SubOrderID) as row_count_src from fact_suborder_journey 
WHERE Suborderdate between '2016-06-01' and GETDATE()-1 ;
```

in dest_table_count i have used the below query:

```
select count(SubOrderID) as row_count_dest from fact_suborder_journey 
WHERE Suborderdate between '2016-06-01' and GETDATE()-1 ;
```

i have added the two variable as int64 in ths ssis package. and map in the result set below you can find the pic what i have done.
[image: variable assignments]
[image: Result_set]

**but After done all this this i am getting this error:
[Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "row_count_src": "The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::row_count_src" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.**
".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent tested this completely but you might be able to do something like this. This creates a loop of your packages and will executes as long as your count variables are different from each other.

**What have i done?**

> 1. First i have a DataFlow Task which moves data from source to
>      destination.
> 2. Then i have an Execute SQL task which basically counts all rows from
>      TableA and maps it to variable count1 eg. Source table
> 3. Then i have an Execute SQL task which basically counts all rows from
>      TableB and maps it to variable count2 eg. Destination Table
> 4. Then i create an Execute Package task where i reference it too it
>      self. Then i make a precedence constraint with an expression saying
>      Count1 != count2.
>
> Because if they are different you want to restart the task. If they
>   are equal the last task Execute Package task will never be executed.

Hope that is something like that?

[image]

Comment: This could end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: @KeithL Yes and No. Because if his counts is equal it will stop. But yes its a strange way, specially since the source and destination always will have the same columns, unless he has a specific business logic or other tables that fills up the destination or some filters on.

Comment: yes something like this what i want .let me try your steps

Comment: @thomas , i have started doing your procedure but now i am getting some other error "[Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to variable "row_count_src": "The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::row_count_src" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.

Comment: @s.kumar Your variable should be a int. And you should set Result set as single row in your execute sql task and map it in resultset properties

Comment: @s.kumar And write 0 in result Name - 0 means first variable. Remember to use single row in Result set under execute sql task and not full resultset

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your challenge correctly...

1. In the data flow task, use a RowCount transformation between source
   and destination to capture the rows written to the destination. This
   will be stored in a variable.
2. In the control flow, get the max row counts available from the log table and store that a variable.
3. Create an execute package tasks that executes this same package and put a precedence constraint before if that compares if variable from Step1 <> variable in Step2.